# How to reduce the probability of page allocation failure?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel, preempt-rt

Are there some methods that could be used by the Linux kernel to the probability of page allocation failure while both CONFIG-MIGRATION and CONFIG-COMPACTION are disabled?

Are there some system settings that could make for this goal besides increasing the value of min_free_bytes and executing `echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`?

Here is an example log of page allocation failure:

```
Hello: page allocation failure: order:9, mode:0x60c0c0(GFP_KERNEL|__GFP_COMP|__GFP_ZERO), nodemask=(null)
Hello cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Mem-Info:
active_anon:56054 inactive_anon:109301 isolated_anon:0
 active_file:110190 inactive_file:91980 isolated_file:0
 unevictable:9375 dirty:1 writeback:0 unstable:0
 slab_reclaimable:22463 slab_unreclaimable:19122
 mapped:101678 shmem:25642 pagetables:7663 bounce:0
 free:456443 free_pcp:0 free_cma:0
Node 0 active_anon:224216kB inactive_anon:437204kB active_file:440760kB inactive_file:367920kB unevictable:37500kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB mapped:406712kB dirty:4kB writeback:0kB shmem:102568kB writeback_tmp:0kB unstable:0kB all_unreclaimable? no
Node 0 DMA free:15892kB min:32kB low:44kB high:56kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:15992kB managed:15892kB mlocked:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 2804 3762 3762
Node 0 DMA32 free:1798624kB min:5836kB low:8704kB high:11572kB active_anon:188040kB inactive_anon:219400kB active_file:184156kB inactive_file:346776kB unevictable:24900kB writepending:0kB present:3017476kB managed:2927216kB mlocked:24900kB kernel_stack:1712kB pagetables:7564kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 958 958
Node 0 Normal free:11256kB min:1992kB low:2972kB high:3952kB active_anon:36084kB inactive_anon:218100kB active_file:257220kB inactive_file:21148kB unevictable:12600kB writepending:4kB present:1048576kB managed:981268kB mlocked:12600kB kernel_stack:5280kB pagetables:23088kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Node 0 DMA: 3*4kB (U) 3*8kB (U) 1*16kB (U) 1*32kB (U) 3*64kB (U) 0*128kB 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (M) 3*4096kB (M) = 15892kB
Node 0 DMA32: 14912*4kB (UME) 13850*8kB (UME) 9325*16kB (UME) 5961*32kB (UME) 3622*64kB (UME) 2359*128kB (UME) 1128*256kB (UME) 524*512kB (M) 194*1024kB (UM) 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 1799872kB
Node 0 Normal: 1643*4kB (UME) 71*8kB (UME) 47*16kB (UM) 35*32kB (M) 38*64kB (M) 1*128kB (M) 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 11572kB
Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
232507 total pagecache pages
7 pages in swap cache
Swap cache stats: add 1015, delete 1008, find 0/1
Free swap  = 995068kB
Total swap = 999420kB
1020511 pages RAM
0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
39417 pages reserved
0 pages hwpoisoned
```

Answer (score 1):

You could play around with vm.min_free_kbytes which tells the kernel to keep such memory free (the unit is kB) under all circumstances.

Docs:

```
min_free_kbytes:

This is used to force the Linux VM to keep a minimum number of kilobytes free. The VM uses this number to compute a watermark[WMARK_MIN] value for each lowmem zone in the system. Each lowmem zone gets a number of reserved free pages based proportionally on its size.

Some minimal amount of memory is needed to satisfy PF_MEMALLOC allocations; if you set this to lower than 1024KB, your system will become subtly broken, and prone to deadlock under high loads.

Setting this too high will OOM your machine instantly.
```

To change this setting permanently you can do (lowering to 16MB):

```
echo "vm.min_free_kbytes=16384" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

To play around and test it everything works you can change it just for current session:

```
sysctl -w vm.min_free_kbytes=16384
```

The source of the information was kernel.org [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt).

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. But to be honesty, it's not a good method. Firstly, the suitable value for min_free_kbytes is not easy to find. Secondly, as the question aforementioned, don't try to set this value. Still thanks to you.